# Is it possible to deploy Android app in Playstore in development mode for testing?

Tags: android, google-play-console

How to deploy an app in Playstore which is in development mode for testing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question and such questions should instead be asked in the relevant support forums or by contacting support. (See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more information.)

Comment: What do you mean by "in development mode"?  Do you mean that it's `android:debuggable="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easy to do.  Use the internal test track just for this purpose.

[image]

Create a list of email addresses for testers that you want to grant access.

[image]

There's an opt-in URL that you can send to your test group. For them it will be visible on Google Play but be aware that it'll probably take 24 hours to show up.

In order to do this you'll have to go through all the setup of Play Store stuff - some required screen shots, privacy policy link, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Good luck @NaseefUmmer - just remember Google's method for deploying test candidates is honestly not as nice as Apple's Testflight. It takes time for updates to trickle through google play

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up! I was just reading it sometimes take 48 hours.